# Numbering Repeating groups of rows - group of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column that shows the numbers 1 to 7 repeating.

```
EDRImportID FileID  value           colnum      rn
2           752454  PN                  1       1
2           752454  NNN                 2       2
2           752454  NNNN                3       3 
2           752454  01/01/2019 00:00    4       4
2           752454  0                   5       5
2           752454  01/01/2019 00:30    6       6
2           752454  0                   7       7
2           752454  NNN                 1       8
2           752454  NNNN                2       9
2           752454  SHOS-1              3       10
2           752454  01/01/2019 00:30    4       11
2           752454  0                   5       12
2           752454  01/01/2019 01:00    6       13
2           752454  0                   7       14
2           752454  NNN                 1       15
2           752454  NNNN                2       16
```

So I'd like the 1st 7 rows to GroupNumber 1, Rows 8 to 14 GroupNumber 2 etc..

The table comes from a csv string held in a table and will always have 7 rows.  This is the SQL that generate the table.

```
SELECT 
    I.EDRImportID,
    FileID,
    value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Record,FileID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as colnum,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FileID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn
FROM Base.Genesis_ImportFile I
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Record, ',') AS Cols
WHERE I.FileType = 'PN'
AND I.Record like 'PN%'
AND I.EDRImportID = 2
AND FileID = 752454
```

Once I have the groupnumber, I need to Pivot the 7 rows for each group into 7 columns.  I tried the code below, but it uses the `MAX` aggregate, which will only return a single row of 7 columns, not several

```
WITH PNColumns AS
(
    SELECT 
        I.EDRImportID,
        FileID,
        value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Record,FileID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn
    FROM Base.Genesis_ImportFile I
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Record, ',') AS Cols
    WHERE I.FileType = 'PN'
    AND I.Record like 'PN%'
    AND I.EDRImportID = 2
    AND FileID = 752454
)

SELECT 
    EDRImportID,
    FileID,
    [2] AS Station,
    [3] AS Unit,
    [4] AS FromDate,
    [5] AS FromMW,
    [6] AS ToDate,
    [7] AS ToMW
FROM PNColumns 
PIVOT(
    MAX(value)
    FOR rn IN ([2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])  
) as PVT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `CEILING`

```
CEILING(CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS DECIMAL)/7) AS Group
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd29b286d1a2654e06a4acbbaff6fa5d)**

**Query will be like**

```
SELECT 
    I.EDRImportID,
    FileID,
    value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Record,FileID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as colnum,
    CEILING(CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS DECIMAL)/7) AS Group
FROM Base.Genesis_ImportFile I
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Record, ',') AS Cols
WHERE I.FileType = 'PN'
AND I.Record like 'PN%'
AND I.EDRImportID = 2
AND FileID = 752454
```

**Output will be**

```
EDRImportID FileID  value           colnum      rn
2           752454  PN                  1       1
2           752454  NNN                 2       1
2           752454  NNNN                3       1 
2           752454  01/01/2019 00:00    4       1
2           752454  0                   5       1
2           752454  01/01/2019 00:30    6       1
2           752454  0                   7       1
2           752454  NNN                 1       2
2           752454  NNNN                2       2
2           752454  SHOS-1              3       2
2           752454  01/01/2019 00:30    4       2
2           752454  0                   5       2
2           752454  01/01/2019 01:00    6       2
2           752454  0                   7       2
2           752454  NNN                 1       3
2           752454  NNNN                2       3
```